# Getting variables in a view composer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I share vars with my views like so:

```
View::share(['test' => $this->test]);
```

How can I get the above value in my view composer?

I am aware of the getData method but this only works with data set like:

```
return view('my-view')->withData($data);
```

How can I get the 'test' value in my view composer?

Comment: you are sharing your variable from the view composer and you want to get the same variable in the view composer ?

Comment: View Share is in the controller construct. I want to then get a var set here in the view composer.

Comment: is your view composer a service provider? Probably it would be useful if you could post the code

Comment: The view composer is the same as the laravel example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
$view->getFactory()->shared('shared_var')
```